# Using Swift Mailer and I'm getting this error?

Tags: php, email

`Warning: is_writable() [function.is-writable]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/tmp) is not within the allowed path(s): (VIRTUAL_DOCUMENT_ROOT) in /www/zxq.net/g/t/a/gtag/htdocs/lib/preferences.php on line 15
blarg!`

This is what is on Line 15 of preferences.php: `if (function_exists('sys_get_temp_dir') && is_writable(sys_get_temp_dir()))`

Any clue what this means? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SiftMailer wants to write a file to the system's temporary directory, which is `/tmp`.

Your host has restricted you from being able to write files outside certain directories. You're not allowed to write a file to `/tmp`.

This warning has informed you of these facts. It means what it says!

Comment: Haha, I figured that after I read it a couple of times, is it possible to delete the line? Or just alter it so it doesnt want to write a file to /tmp?

Comment: Do you even know if it does so? This is a warning, not an error, and it looks like that code is explicitly there to check if it's allowed before doing so. If you don't want to see the warning, change your error reporting level.

Comment: I changed the error reporting level only to be back to square one. I was looking for an alternative mailing method for my website to get around the bans the web hosting puts on, but swiftmailer is also blocked. Thanks for your help anyway, it did work after all!

Comment: http://www.sendgrid.com http://www.postmarkapp.com http://www.mailchimp.com http://aws.amazon.com/ses/